# Animal Crossing Pocket Camp error

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I keep getting an error with this code and I don’t know how to fix it or what it even is.

[image]

Comment: How long have you been getting the error for? "Please try again later" usually really does mean that you should try again later, often due to a temporary server or connection problem.

Comment: @Broneironaut I just got the game last night and tried to play it again this morning and got the error. Since I’ve only gotten it today so far I wouldn’t be surprised if it is just a connection issue or something similar.

Comment: @Broneironaut if it’s not a server issue then it’s most likely my internet and not my device. I’ve never had issues with my phone but sometimes my internet is slow or it cuts out at times.

Comment: Mornings seem to be the worst for those. In the morning its always hard to get to login, but in the evening I experience no problems.

Answer (score 2):

The servers have been unstable since the launch.

It's like that for every game that needs a heavy connection to the server. The servers can't handle the load of all the people trying to connect at the same time.

Continue trying until you log in. It should be stable in a week or so.

EDIT: Thing that seems weird is that the error code seems to always start by 802- but the last 4 numbers seem to vary.

EDIT2: Seems the servers have now came back to being stable. If you still encounter the error, now the possibility that it's you is high.

Comment: This morning I’ve gotten about 4 different error codes. All starting with 802 but ending differently. And usually after I push retry it lets me log in and continue but when I try to do anything it gives me another error.

Comment: Yeah its inconsitent. I've got some before the title screen, after; most frustrating was this morning that was getting into the game, but getting the dc error after talking to anybody